# Multiple local sites in subdirectories using nginx

Tags: 10

I want to install both Drupal 9 and Drupal 10 on my localhost. I had based Nginx config on [Nginx Drupal recipe](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/drupal/) and following is the part of Nginx config that I'm struggling with:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/drupal10;
    index index.php;

    location /drupal10 {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^ /drupal10/index.php;
    }
}
... and then the rest of configuration as per nginx drupal recipe
```

Similarly for nginx configuration of drupal9 subdirectory:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/drupal9;
    index index.php;

    location /drupal9 {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^ /drupal9/index.php;
    }
}
... and then the rest of configuration as per nginx drupal recipe
```

But I'm getting "404 Not Found". What could be the correct configuration?

Comment: There is a lot more configuration required for Drupal with nginx: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/drupal/ You should base your configuration from the official one, then ask questions.

Comment: @cilefen that's true, I had based my configuration on nginx drupal recipes but I just put in the question only directives that I believe is impacting the setup to avoid long post. Do you think I should put the whole configuration for the question to be more clear?

Comment: You will save yourself much trouble by using DDEV for local Drupal development.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with following configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  root /var/www;

  index index.php;

  location /drupal9 {
    alias /var/www/drupal9;
    try_files $uri /drupal9/index.php;
  }

  location /drupal10 {
    alias /var/www/drupal10;
    try_files $uri /drupal10/index.php;
  }

# Additional settings for PHP and Drupal from nginx drupal recipe[1]
# ...
```